# Finding Keywords In a Specific Sequence In Kibana DSL Query

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

How can I match a phrase which contains some keywords in a specific order?

```
GET /_myIndex/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
          {"match_phrase_prefix": {"CommandLine": "hidden*downloadstring*"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above, I want to find any sequence of command line string which contains the term `hidden` and at some point after that the term `downloadstring` with anything that comes after that.

Is that the right API for that search or is there a better way of finding it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for a [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

Here's an example from my project. I hope it helps you formulate your query:

```
GET my-index-*/_search
{
   "_source": ["my.access.url"],
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : { "my.access.url" : "*downloadLinkOrStuff*" }
    }
}
```